# Find the value of $\lim_{x\rightarrow {0}^{+}}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{(-1)}^{n-1}\frac{1}{n!{x}^{n}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, power-series

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow {0}^{+}}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{(-1)}^{n-1}\frac{1}{n!{x}^{n}}=?$$

I found this question during my study.
In my opinion ,it is not  difficult to solve ,but it is interesting.
So I  want to bring this question to share with everyone.

If you are interested, you can try to solve it .

Comment: The limit as $x\to 0$ does not exist, but the limit as $x\to 0^+$ does.

Comment: $\to 0^{-}$ or $\to 0^{+}$ ?.

Comment: @Felix Marin Oh, that's my carelessness.I correct it now.

Comment: @FelixMarin:  I am not good at minus signs, but the series looks like $1-e^{-1/x}$. As $x$ approaches $0$ through negative values, the thing becomes very large negative.

Comment: "Share" Meaning you already have a solution?

Comment: @Did:  Yes .My solution just like the following answer.but  I want to find more solutions as much as possible,can you help me?

Comment: Sorry but I fail to see the point.

Answer (score 2):

$${(-1)}^{n-1}\frac{1}{n!{x}^{n}}=-\frac{\left(-\frac1x\right)^n}{n!}$$

$$\implies\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{(-1)}^{n-1}\frac{1}{n!{x}^{n}}=-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-\frac1x\right)^n}{n!}=-e^{-\frac1x}$$

$$\implies(-1)^{0-1}\frac1{0! x^0}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{(-1)}^{n-1}\frac{1}{n!{x}^{n}} =-e^{-\frac1x}$$

$$\implies\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{(-1)}^{n-1}\frac{1}{n!{x}^{n}} =-e^{-\frac1x}+1=-\frac1{e^{\frac1x}}+1$$

Comment: You are right ! I want to find more solutions as much as possible.